# Cannot grant UNLIMITED TABLESPACE to created user

Tags: plsql, privileges

I am using oracle 10g. I have a database user TDM_DD which executes a procedure in which it creates a schema/user and tables in it. While doing so I have to grant 'UNLIMITED TABLESPACE' privilege to the newly created schema. However I am getting error *"ORA-01031: insufficient privileges"* Need help!!

Comment: the error message tells you: YOUR CODE must run with the privileges needed (talk to your admin).

Comment: I have installed oracle on my local machine and I cant get admin help so quickly. Any help from here really appritiated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only grant the UNLIMITED TABLESPACE privilege as a user that is allowed to grant it, such as the SYSTEM user. You will need to give your TDM_DD user the privileges to be able to have it grant the UNLIMITED TABLESPACE privilege to someone else.

Comment: I executed the query "GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO TDM_DD" using the system user, but TDM_DD still cant provide access to new schema. I am new to the oracle, I searched a lot but wont unserstand how I can give privilege to TDM_DD so that it can grant other.

Comment: Try granting it with the admin option: GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO "TDM_DD" WITH ADMIN OPTION

Comment: It solved my problem, TDM_DD can provide grant privilege to new schema. Thanks Datajam Ltd